# Open a function in Python Spyder, like I do with MATLAB

Tags: python, spyder

In MATLAB, there I can place the cursor on a function name and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, the file containing the function will automatically open. Is there any way I can do something similar with Python, within the Spyder IDE?

Comment: How about: Ctrl+Click on function

Comment: Rightclick -> Goto Definition or Ctrl + G

Comment: @pwagner I just tried, but that menu option is always deactivated, do you know why?

Comment: @Wolf: all three methods work for me. I would speculate that it may depend on whether you have installed pylint or not. (or one of the other code-intospection modules that Sypder uses)

Comment: @Peter thanks for the research. I have a plain spyder installation (especially pylint), and both, Ctrl+Click and Ctrl+G, work whereas *Goto Definition* is inactive. Strange!

Comment: This is great.  But what I would use more is to be able to do this from the iPython console window.  I can't find anyway to make that jump.

Comment: not in spyder, but you can do that in vscode (tested with the interactive windows)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Spyder you can jump to the definition of a function (or class) by holding **CTRL** and clicking on the function (or class) name/reference. If that definition is in an other file, that file will be opened.

> Ctrl + Leftclick

**EDIT**
as commented by @pwagner

> Rightclick -> Goto Definition

and

> Ctrl + G

also work

Comment: I have some problem with this:
1) This works only for user-defined functions. For example, if I write sum([1,2,3]) and GoTo definition of that function, nothing happens. 
2) This works only in the editor. If I try Ctrl+Leftclick on the Ipython console, nothing happens.

Comment: @Vaaal: most buildin functions are not implemented in python, so I would not expect to find python-sourcecode for them. In IPython use `functionname??` to access the buildin help.

Comment: @Vaal With Ctrl+I, you get some doc shown in the *Object inspector* view.

Comment: So there is no way to select a function in the console and open it within the editor, even for a user defined one?

Comment: @Vaaal: for user defined functions functionname?? prints the source code into the console, but thats not what you want. I have no further idea, my guess is that it is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Altough the answer given above is correct, it didn't work for me. Here is what I ended up doing:

With the help of [this post](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2780), I figured out that my Ubuntu 14.04 was missing some python packages for spyder to work properly.

Go to `Help -> Optional Dependencies` and check which of the packages are missing or not in the required version. Copy to clipboard the list and paste it into an editor and store the file as `requirements.txt`. Edit the file such that the list or required packages has the following format

```
jedi==0.8.1
pep8==0.6
psutil==0.3
pyflakes==0.5.0
pylint==0.25
rope==0.9.2
sympy==0.7.3
```

Now do

```
sudo pip install -r requirements.txt
```

on that file. Restart spyder. It should work now!