# Reversing ctrl+leftclick in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I have a very simple question. I started using Spyder and have used ctrl + LeftClick to inspect the source code of a class, method, function, etc.

How do I "go back" once I have ctrl+LeftClick-ed? I've looked around a bit but have not found this simple thing (for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27439431/open-a-function-in-python-spyder-like-i-do-with-matlab) is what I am trying to reverse). Perhaps the problem is that the description of the question is hard to put into non-common words.

Answer (score 0):

This should work I have tried it :

> Press `Ctrl + W`